# "This session is provisioning a new connection; concurrent operations are not permitted" error using SQLAlchemy UOW and starlette_admin

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, unit-of-work, starlette

I am tried to implement transactions in fastapi project. (routes -> Services layer -> Unit of Work -> Repositories)

This is my base UOW:

```py
class BaseUnitOfWork(UnitOfWorkInterface):
    def __init__(self, session_factory: Callable[[], AsyncSession]) -> None:
        self._session_factory = session_factory

    async def __aenter__(self) -> Self:
        self.session = self._session_factory()
        self._init_repos()

        return self

    @abstractmethod
    def _init_repos(self) -> None:
        """
        Usage:
            - Inherit BaseUnitOfWork and define this method
            - use method _register_repo to attach db session to you're repositories
        Example:
            from your_repositories import User, Profile

            class MyUnitOfWork(BaseUnitOfWork):
                def _init_repos(self):
                    self.users = self._register_repo(UserRepository)
                    self.profiles = self._register_repo(ProfileRepository)
        """
        pass

    def _register_repo(self, repo: type[R]) -> R:
        return repo(self.session)
        
    async def __aexit__(
        self,
        exception: type[BaseException] | None,
        value: BaseException | None,
        traceback: TracebackType | None,
    ) -> None:
        if exception:
            await self.session.rollback()
        else:
            await self.session.commit()

        await self.session.close()

    async def save(self):
        await self.session.commit()

    async def undo(self):
        await self.session.rollback()
```

This is my app-level UOW:

```py
class UnitOfWork(BaseUnitOfWork):
    def _init_repos(self) -> None:
        self.users = self._register_repo(UserDAL)
        self.vocabularies = self._register_repo(VocabularySetDAL)
        self.language_pairs = self._register_repo(LanguagePairDAL)
```

UOW is used as dependency in Service layer:

```py
class UserService:
    def __init__(self, uow: UnitOfWork) -> None:
        self._uow = uow

    async def get_or_create_by_id(self, id: int) -> User:
        async with self._uow as uow:
            user = await uow.users.get_or_create(id=id)

        return user
    
    async def get_by_id(self, id: int) -> User | None:
        async with self._uow as uow:
            user = await uow.users.get_by_id(id)

        return user
```

And then I create services components via:

```py
users_service = UserService(UnitOfWork(async_session_maker))
vocabularies_service = VocabularyService(UnitOfWork(async_session_maker))
```

And use it by importing services to my routes.

Then i call my regular api endpoints all works well, but if i open my starlette admin dashboard, I've receive error:
`This session is provisioning a new connection; concurrent operations are not permitted`
This occurs only when I open the edit page with model that need to load additional child models.

And further error displays when I terminate app:

``` ERROR:sqlalchemy.pool.impl.AsyncAdaptedQueuePool:The garbage collector is trying to clean up non-checked-in connection <AdaptedConnection <asyncpg.connection.Connection object at 0x112d2a020>>, which will be terminated.  Please ensure that SQLAlchemy pooled connections are returned to the pool explicitly, either by calling ``close()`` or by using appropriate context managers to manage their lifecycle. ```

it seems the problem in `close()` method I've called in my uow context manager (SQLAlchemy `asyncio`) and sessions that uow creates may conflicts with starlete-admin sessions (Starlete `anyio`) that creates under the hood.

I've tried to wrap my `close()` method to `shield` asyncio method:

```py
    async def __aexit__(
        self,
        exception: type[BaseException] | None,
        value: BaseException | None,
        traceback: TracebackType | None,
    ) -> None:
        if exception:
            await self.session.rollback()
        else:
            await self.session.commit()

        await asyncio.shield(self.session.close())
```

But it not caused any changes.

The full message of exception:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
  + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 108, in __call__
  |     response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
  |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette_admin/contrib/sqla/middleware.py", line 24, in dispatch
  |     return await call_next(request)
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 84, in call_next
  |     raise app_exc
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 70, in coro
  |     await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/sessions.py", line 86, in __call__
  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send_wrapper)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 106, in __call__
  |     async with anyio.create_task_group() as task_group:
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 658, in __aexit__
  |     raise BaseExceptionGroup(
  | ExceptionGroup: unhandled errors in a TaskGroup (1 sub-exception)
  +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
    | Traceback (most recent call last):
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 108, in __call__
    |     response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette_admin/auth.py", line 277, in dispatch
    |     await self.provider.is_authenticated(request)
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/app/backend/admin/auth.py", line 53, in is_authenticated
    |     current_user = await AuthService.get_user_from_token(token)
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/app/backend/auth/auth.py", line 42, in get_user_from_token
    |     user = await users_service.get_by_id(user_id)
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/app/backend/users/services.py", line 18, in get_by_id
    |     async with self._uow as uow:
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/app/backend/db/unitofwork.py", line 71, in __aexit__
    |     await self.session.commit()
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 1011, in commit
    |     await greenlet_spawn(self.sync_session.commit)
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 179, in greenlet_spawn
    |     result = context.switch(*args, **kwargs)
    |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1969, in commit
    |     trans.commit(_to_root=True)
    |   File "<string>", line 2, in commit
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 103, in _go
    |     self._raise_for_prerequisite_state(fn.__name__, current_state)
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 946, in _raise_for_prerequisite_state
    |     raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
    | sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This session is provisioning a new connection; concurrent operations are not permitted (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/isce)
    +------------------------------------

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  + Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
  |     result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
  |     return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 292, in __call__
  |     await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
  |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
  |     raise exc
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
  |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
  |     raise exc
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
  |     await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
  |     raise e
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
  |     await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 443, in handle
  |     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
  |     await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
  |     raise exc
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
  |     await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 106, in __call__
  |     async with anyio.create_task_group() as task_group:
  |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 658, in __aexit__
  |     raise BaseExceptionGroup(
  | ExceptionGroup: unhandled errors in a TaskGroup (1 sub-exception)
  +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
    | Traceback (most recent call last):
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 97, in receive
    |     return self.receive_nowait()
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 92, in receive_nowait
    |     raise WouldBlock
    | anyio.WouldBlock
    | 
    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    | 
    | Traceback (most recent call last):
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 78, in call_next
    |     message = await recv_stream.receive()
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/streams/memory.py", line 112, in receive
    |     raise EndOfStream
    | anyio.EndOfStream
    | 
    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    | 
    | Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 108, in __call__
    |     response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
    |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette_admin/contrib/sqla/middleware.py", line 24, in dispatch
    |     return await call_next(request)
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 84, in call_next
    |     raise app_exc
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 70, in coro
    |     await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/sessions.py", line 86, in __call__
    |     await self.app(scope, receive, send_wrapper)
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 106, in __call__
    |     async with anyio.create_task_group() as task_group:
    |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 658, in __aexit__
    |     raise BaseExceptionGroup(
    | ExceptionGroup: unhandled errors in a TaskGroup (1 sub-exception)
    +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
      | Traceback (most recent call last):
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 108, in __call__
      |     response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
      |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette_admin/auth.py", line 277, in dispatch
      |     await self.provider.is_authenticated(request)
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/app/backend/admin/auth.py", line 53, in is_authenticated
      |     current_user = await AuthService.get_user_from_token(token)
      |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/app/backend/auth/auth.py", line 42, in get_user_from_token
      |     user = await users_service.get_by_id(user_id)
      |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/app/backend/users/services.py", line 18, in get_by_id
      |     async with self._uow as uow:
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/app/backend/db/unitofwork.py", line 71, in __aexit__
      |     await self.session.commit()
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 1011, in commit
      |     await greenlet_spawn(self.sync_session.commit)
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 179, in greenlet_spawn
      |     result = context.switch(*args, **kwargs)
      |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1969, in commit
      |     trans.commit(_to_root=True)
      |   File "<string>", line 2, in commit
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state_changes.py", line 103, in _go
      |     self._raise_for_prerequisite_state(fn.__name__, current_state)
      |   File "/Users/apple/Desktop/proggraming/fastbot/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 946, in _raise_for_prerequisite_state
      |     raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
      | sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This session is provisioning a new connection; concurrent operations are not permitted (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/isce)
```

Comment: The only way I found around this problem is to use a `connection` (via `with engine.connect() as connection:` instead of a `Session` or `sessionmaker`, when working with an async engine. 
I found this in this thread: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/10687
They've also added it to their documentation: https://gerrit.sqlalchemy.org/c/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/+/4993